# Does Scala automatically wrap fields?

Tags: scala, variables, properties

Someone once told me that all public fields, by nature of the language were automatically wrapped in getters and setters. And I believed that until I checked the kind in IDEA's intellisense.

So say we have a simple class

```
class Something {
  val a = 5
}
```

Then writing `(new Something).` IDEA would show `a` as being a value.

Conversely however, doing the exact same thing in Eclipse, `a` would be shown as a `def`, which puts me on the fence here.

Which one's correct? Is the value wrapped in a function at compile time, and IDEA is simply being confusing? Or is it just a value/variable and I've been mistaken the whole time?

Comment: Where does Scala IDE show that it is a def?

Comment: @sschaef when you mouse over I believe, after it's written I mean.. It's been a while since I last used the Scala IDE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A field and a getter are being generated, however the getter is not prefixed by get as would be the expectation in Java.  It is instead given the same name as the field.  To confirm this we can dissect the class file that is generated by scalac by using javap.

```
first compile Something.scala
javap -p Something.class 

public class starling.launcher.utils.Something implements scala.ScalaObject {
  private final int a;
  public int a();
  public starling.launcher.utils.Something();
}
```

and then just for fun, here is the jvm byte codes for a(), which confirms that it is indeed a straight forward getter method for a field.

```
javap -c Something.class 

public int a();
  Code:
     0: aload_0       
     1: getfield      #11                 // Field a:I
     4: ireturn
```

>

If we go on to change val to var, then the code changes to the following.  Which includes a setter method, which has the rather 'unusual' name of a_$eq.

```
public class starling.launcher.utils.Something implements scala.ScalaObject {
  private int a;
  public int a();          // getter method
  public void a_$eq(int);  // setter method
  public starling.launcher.utils.Something();
}
```

and to confirm that a_$eq is a setter method, here is its byte code.

```
public void a_$eq(int);
  Code:
     0: aload_0       
     1: iload_1       
     2: putfield      #11                 // Field a:I
     5: return
```

Comment: does `var` generate a setter too then?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee It does, yes.  The name is really odd though, it is a_$eq(int).

Comment: So it's just IntelliJ IDEA that's being odd showing it as a value rather than a def, thanks!

Comment: @ElectricCoffee it's not *odd*, most of time you're will be bothered by that getters/setters noise, so it's simply shows you the essence.

Comment: @om-nom-nom bad choice of words on my part

Comment: @ElectricCoffee by the way, IDEA had it's own scala compiler, independent of scalac (at least it was so year or two ago), so you could observe quite different behaviour compiling code with vanilla scalac and the one bundled with IDEA. In case of doubt, if you're interested in underpinnings, fallback to scalac/javap

Comment: @om-nom-nom I believe sbt takes care of downloading a compiler though, so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @ElectricCoffee [they're both presented](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2014/01/30/try-faster-scala-compiler-in-intellij-idea-13-0-2/) and looks like IDEA's is set by default, so no, this should be a problem sometimes (though not related to your question).